# How do I use gradle application plugin to run a project with multiple packages?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project with multiple packages. I have a single build.gradle file at the root level of the project. When I issue gradle build, I get a build folder inside each of the packages with the package jar dropped inside it. One of the packages have the main class. I would like to use the application plugin to help me with this. When I add application plugin and the main class name to the root build.gradle file, execute gradle run, I get an error that the class is not found. The reason is because gradle is looking for build folder with classes and resources folder inside the build folder. I dont see them generated and I assume this is to do with the multi package scenario. How do I make the application plugin work for multiple packages?

Comment: When you say "package" I think you mean "project".  If that's so, please update your question.  This link talks about multi-project builds: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "projects" not "packages" then the way to run a subproject, that has the application plugin applied, is by naming the project on the command line as follows.

```
gradle sub_project_name:run
```

In a multi-project build you may have a structure as follows:

```
root_project
 |
 +-- sub1
 |
 +-- sub2
 .
 .
 .
```

If `sub1` contains the code

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = com.example.MyMain
```

Then you can run the MyMain class with the command

```
gradle sub1:run
```

All this is detailed in this link: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: I have a question in similar lines. When the 'application' plugin is applied to one of the subprojects, in this case **sub1** then the `gradle build` is going to generate the distribution as sub1.zip and sub1.tar. The distribution name is expected to be same as the name of root project. How do we address this naming issue?